# How to create multiple data frames with one loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After hours of banging my head with my professor, I was finally able to read in a data file, navigate to the data I am concerned with, and build a pandas dataframe with some of that data.  My problem now, is that I need to do this 30 times, but cant figure out how to automate this while not overriding my data and while creating new columns.

```
Filename = 'Al_v11.o' #Variable assigned to the file name
File_open = open(Filename,'r') #the r is for read access #opens my MCNP output in memory

Line = File_open.readline()  #Line will now call the command readline, which reads a single line of the MCNP file per time called

counts=0 #1tally appears mutiple times, this allows us to navigate to the second occurance. 
while (Line[0:15] != '1tally        1' or counts < 2): #[0:15] is necessary to constain the while loop, otherwise it will compare 1tally to a whole line and not find a match
    Line = File_open.readline() #this reads a bunch of lines as the while loop iterates
    if Line[0:15] == '1tally        1':
        counts +=1  #we want the second iteration of 1tally
#print (counts)
print (File_open.readline())
print (File_open.readline())
print (File_open.readline())
print (File_open.readline())
print (File_open.readline())
print (File_open.readline()) #the data starts 6 lines below 1tally, thus we need these

myarray= []
while (Line[0:11] != '      total'): #total is the last line, we do not care about it
    Line = File_open.readline()
    if Line[0:11] != '      total': 
        myarray = np.append(myarray, np.fromstring(Line, dtype = float, sep='   ')) #writing data to myarray throughout whileloop

data = np.zeros((int(myarray.size/3),2)) #reshapes the array into a X,2       
data[:,0] = myarray[0:-1:3] #populates the first column
data[:,1] = myarray[1:-1:3] #populates the second column

Foil_1_Front = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Energy', 'Counts']) #creates pandas dataframe
```

I do not know how to iterate this throughout all 60 of my Energy and Counts columns (30 each), without overwriting myarray each time.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a way more efficient way to do what you're trying to do, but it's hard to help you without some sample data. Do you want to create 30 DataFrames with Energy and Counts columns ? Do you want to create one dataframe with 30 sets of Energy and Counts columns? Is `File_open` a string?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Ideally I would like a single dataframe in which my headers are something like 'Energy1''Counts1'Energy2''Counts2'  etc. out to 30.

Comment: Could you give a minimal, complete example of what the input file might contain, and what the corresponding output should be? I don't understand what the reshaping is supposed to do. Also, when you say "do this 30 times", do you mean that there are 30 separate files to join data from, or that you need to repeat the processing on the same file, or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have one file with 30 separate sections in it containing data.  As far as an example goes, in each of the 30 sections, I have 3 columns of data, 161 lines in each column.  My reshaping commands are to reshape this (483,1) list into two columns, which are then put into the data frame.

Comment: What's the structure of you file? Is it a text file? a table? a json?

Comment: @JuanC it is a text file with several thousand lines, only about a fourth applies to what I need.